# The Replica returned an error: code 3, message: "Canister ryjl3-tyaaa-aaaaa-aaaba-cai has no update method 'top'"

Tags: motoko

I started develop in Motoko Programming Language. I try call function from my terminal but when I enter: `dfx canister call dbankk_backend topUp`

```
import Debug "mo:base/Debug";

actor Dbank {
  var currentValue = 300;
currentValue := 100;

//like const variable
// let id = 534543546543;

//Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));

public func topUp() {
  currentValue += 2;
  Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
};

// top();

}
```

But it says:

```
Error: Failed update call.
Caused by: Failed update call.
The Replica returned an error: code 3, message: "Canister ryjl3-tyaaa-aaaaa-aaaba-cai has no update method 'topUp'"
```

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uutl1.png)

I expect to see in terminal that `CurrentValue` growing up in 2.

Comment: Have you first correctly ran `dfx deploy`?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `dfx deploy` and running the command again.
The Canister was probably updated in the code but has not been deployed to make the changes, so the function `topUp` has not been compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with running `dfx deploy` after exposing your `topUp` function then proceeding to run `dfx canister call <your project> topUp`. You see, when you make some changes on your `motoko` file, how will it know about the changes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

*["We're a little bit different from other sites."](/tour)*

You have posted this as an *answer*, but it appears you are attempting to reply to another answer. We ask that each answer be unique or provide additional value.  Simply agreeing with and commenting on another answer should be left for the comments.

Comment: When you gain some additional reputation, you will be able to comment on others' posts, upvote the answer you agree with, or even offer a bounty on the answer to reward it.

You can gain reputation by posting quality questions and answers, or by improving existing questions/answers by [editing](/help/editing) them. Thanks!